# Infinite product: $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}.$$I have no idea how I can start. Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you factor the polynomials $X^3-1$ and $X^3+1$?

Comment: Yes I tried, but then I don't know what to do.

Comment: What did you get for the factorisations?

Comment: I have gotten $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(k-1)(k^2+k+1)}{(k+1)(k^2-k+1)}$.

Comment: a possible hint, there are identities for sums and products of $k^n$, these can be taken to a limit, then the result is the quotient of these formulas

Comment: Okay. You see how the $\frac{k-1}{k+1}$ factors telescope? Take a close look at the $\frac{k^2+k+1}{k^2-k+1}$ factors to see they telescope too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I saw.

Answer (score 15):

The main idea is to use a telescope product of the form $ \prod \frac{b_j}{b_{j+2}} \frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}$. We have$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k=2}^n \frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=2}^n \frac{k-1}{k+1} \frac{k^2+k+1}{k^2-k+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=2}^n \frac{k-1}{(k+2)-1} \frac{(k+1)^2-(k+1)+1}{k^2-k+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 \cdot 2}{n \cdot (n+1)}\frac{n^2+n+1}{4-2+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{3} \frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2+n}=\frac{2}{3}.$$